# Duplicated business logic in Ruby and SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, design-patterns, architecture

I have a PORO (Plain Old Ruby Object) to deal with some business logic. It receives an `ActiveRecord` object and classify it. For the sake of simplicity, take the following as an example:

```
class Classificator
    STATES = {
      1 => "Positive",
      2 => "Neutral",
      3 => "Negative"
    }

    def initializer(item)
      @item = item
    end

    def name
      STATES.fetch(state_id)
    end

    private

    def state_id
      return 1 if @item.value > 0
      return 2 if @item.value == 0
      return 3 if @item.value < 0
    end
end
```

However, I also want to do queries that groups objects based on these `state_id` "virtual attribute". I'm currently dealing with that by creating this attribute in the SQL queries and using it in `GROUP BY` statements. See the example:

```
class Classificator::Query
  SQL_CONDITIONS = {
    1 => "items.value > 0",
    2 => "items.value = 0",
    3 => "items.value < 0"
  }

  def initialize(relation = Item.all)
    @relation = relation
  end

  def count
    @relation.select(group_conditions).group('state_id').count
  end

  private
  def group_conditions
    'CASE ' + SQL_CONDITIONS.map do |k, v|
      'WHEN ' + v.to_s + " THEN " + k.to_s
    end.join(' ') + " END AS state_id"
  end
end
```

This way, I can get this business logic into SQL and make this kind of query in a very efficient way.

The problem is: I have duplicated business logic. It exists in "ruby" code, to classify a single object and also in "SQL" to classify a collection of objects in database-level.

Is it a bad practice? Is there a way to avoid this? I actually was able to do this, doing the following:

```
item = Item.find(4)
items.select(group_conditions).where(id: item.id).select('state_id')
```

But by doing this, I loose the ability to classify objects that are not persisted in database. The other way out would be classifying each object in ruby, using an Iterator, but then I would lose database performance.

It's seem to be unavoidable to keep duplicated business logic if I need the best of the two cases. But I just want to be sure about this. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather keep database simple, and put logic in Ruby code as much as possible. Since classification is not stored in database, I won't expect the queries to return it.

My solution is to define a concern which will be included into ActiveRecord model classes.

```
module Classified
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  STATES = {
    1 => "Positive",
    2 => "Neutral",
    3 => "Negative"
  }

  included do
    def state_name
      STATES.fetch(state_id)
    end

    private

    def state_id
      (0 <=> value.to_i) + 2
    end
  end
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Classified
end
```

And I fetch items from database just as usual.

```
items = Item.where(...)
```

Since each `item` knows its own classification value, I don't have to ask database for it.

```
items.each do |item|
  puts item.state_name
end
```

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord itself implies a degree of coupling between your persistence and business logic. However, as much as the pattern allows, and if you don't have **real** performance constraints, the first option should be to keep your persistence code as dumb as possible, and move this "classification" (which is clearly a business rule) away from the database as much as possible.

The rationale is that database-related code is more expensive to change (especially as your system is already in production) and generally more difficult and slower to test than pure business logic.

Answer (score -1):

Is there any chance to introduce trigger in the database? If so, I would go with “calculated” field `state_id` in the database, that changes it’s value on both `INSERT` and `UPDATE` (this will bring even more productivity benefit) and this code in ruby:

```
def state_if
  return @item.state_id if @item.state_id # persistent object

  case @item.value
  when 0 then 2
  when -Float::INFINITY...0 then 3
  else 1
  end
end
```

Comment: It would probably improve performance by updating this field in database. However, I believe I would still have duplicated business logic, right? Both on database trigger and on the `state_if` method.

Comment: @JoãoDaniel yes and no. Whether the business logic is absolutely the same for persistent and non-persistent objects, with this approach you might put all the logic into DB layer and do `start_transaction ⇒ read_state ⇒ rollback` hack.